# Know how to detect form fields name and type but can not set value?

Tags: c#, pdflib

I am trying to set the values of a few form fields in a (template) pdf which is created by the designer.

Already found out to detect the name and type of the fields.
So I know which form fields there are:

```
String res = pdflib.pcos_get_string(indoc, "fields[" + f + "]/fullname");
String fieldtype = pdflib.pcos_get_string(indoc, "fields[" + f + "]/FT");
```

Is it possible to set a value with pdflib?
I can not find any good (and simple) working example.

Comment: Yes, I did. Unfortunatelythat method does not exist... :(

Comment: Figured  it wouldn't hurt to ask. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with the [PDFlib pCOS Interface](https://www.pdflib.com/products/pcos/) you can only read the information but not change it. PDFlib does not provide any functionality for manipulating existing PDF documents.

Comment: Thank you, that confirms my thoughts. But pdflib offers a fill_block() method. With that you can set a value. But that only seems to work on 'pdflib blocks', a special kind of pdflib block/field. That means the existing pdf should  (already) contain this type of block...is that correct?

Comment: With the PDFlib Personalization Server you can include PDFlib blocks on a PDF. You can fill blocks via fill_*block() when creating a new document and importing PDF pages which contains blocks. The explanation on https://www.pdflib.com/products/pdflib-family/pdflib-personalization-server-pps/ "PDF Form Fields or PDFlib Blocks?" may be of interest here. PPS Sample are included in the PDFlib package (starter_block) or also available in the PDFlib cookbook https://www.pdflib.com/pdflib-cookbook/blocks/

Comment: Thank you! I think you are correct. I'll try the sample starter_block today (overlooked this sample...:( ..it's already on my machine! ). The only disadvantage of this 'solution' is that you'll need Adobe Acrobat Pro with the plug-in installed to make it work. But we'll fix that  issue later..first let's give it a try with the sample...:)

Comment: Confirmed. The sample starter_block pdf works fine. Now I am able to modify content in the pdf within these predefined (PDFLIB) blocks.